# How to disable parent checkbox of that group when you select any item in children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the parent checkbox of that group upon selection of radio button. I was able to disable the checkbox of that element upon radio selection. But I also just want to disable the parent checkbox of that group.

Here is the Javascript

```
 $('.taxradio').change(function () {

     $('.taxcheck').attr('disabled', false);
     $(this).next("input[type='checkbox']").attr({
         checked: false,
         disabled: true
     });
    $(this).closest(".leve2check input[type='checkbox']").attr({
         checked: false,
         disabled: true
     });
```

]

What I want to do is upon radio button check, disable the checkbox of its parent and itself.

Example: If I select D2 radio button disable D2 checkbox and D checkbox.
If I select C1 radio button than disable C1 checkbox and C checkbox.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/voo0m6z7/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you're using to find the parent element is wrong.

`.closest()` is used to find the closest ancestor (parent/grandparent) that matches your selector, which, needs to be an element, not a class.

Since the focused radio is not **contained** by `leve2check`, it will return you nothing.

In this case, you need to first find the parent `li` that contains your radio. For that, i have added a class (`level2`) to it. And then use `.find()` to get it's child `leve2Check`.

See if the code below works the way you want:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.rad').change(function() {
    var $currLvlChk = $(this).next("input[type='checkbox']");
    var $lvl2Chk = $(this).parents('li.level2').find('.leve2check');

    $('.chk').attr('disabled', false);

    $currLvlChk.attr({
      checked: false,
      disabled: true
    });

    $lvl2Chk.attr({
      checked: false,
      disabled: true
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="lvl1">
  <a>
    <h4>A</h4>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <!--Level 2-->
    <li class="level2">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk leve2check" />
      <label>B</label>
      <ul>
        <!--Level 3-->
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>B1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>B2</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level2">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk leve2check" />
      <label>C</label>
      <ul>
        <!--Level 3-->
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>C1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>C2</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level2">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk leve2check" />
      <label>D</label>
      <ul>
        <!--Level 3-->
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>D1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" class="rad" name="primaryradio" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
          <label>D2</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Yeah that a better way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all.